# How to set the option selected in a select field with vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<span class="input-group-btn" style="min-width: 100px">
            <select class="form-control" v-model="field.related_field">
                <option value="null"></option>
                <option v-for="f in fields" v-bind:value="f.id" v-if="f.id != ''" v-bind:selected="f.id == field.related_field ? true : false">{{ f.label }}</option>
            </select>
        </span>
```

This is my code in vue js. I am trying to set the option selected if the user submitted anything before when I am fetching from database. I tried to bind with the selected attribute. Can anyone help with this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-model` takes care of this for you. Just set the expression you are binding with `v-model` to the value you want.

```
this.field.related_field = <value you want to default to>
```